# Vertical Text with DirectWrite (+270° rotated)

Tags: directx-11, direct2d, directwrite

I need to show vertical text in my direct2d application. Following text formatting code rotates the text +90°.

```
m_textFormat->SetReadingDirection(DWRITE_READING_DIRECTION_BOTTOM_TO_TOP));
m_textFormat->SetFlowDirection(DWRITE_FLOW_DIRECTION_RIGHT_TO_LEFT));
```

[image]

But I want to rotate the text +270° like the following:

[image]

There are many other options in SetReadingDirection and SetFlowDirection. But none of them is working. The following sample also rotates only +90°: [DirectWrite vertical text sample](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/DirectWrite-vertical-text-c16efdcb)

If I manually rotate the text, it looks blur:

```
renderTarget->SetTransform(Matrix3x2F::Rotation(m_rotation, Point2F(left + height / 2.0f, top + (bottom - top) / 2.0f)));
```

Can anyone please help me with this?

Regards,

Comment: directx-11 tag does not look relevant here.

Comment: It doesn't seem blur for me if I rotate it with Transform => [Test DiretWritte rotated](https://i.ibb.co/C9j55Tv/DWrite-Rotate.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think rotation angle is to user in this context, and it shouldn't be. It's a part of layout process that you don't need to interfere with, it's about displaying horizontal scripts along with vertical ones, see [1].

Regarding visual artifacts of transforms, that sounds normal, look at `CreateGlyphRunAnalysis()` method that takes transform into account, maybe that will give you better results.

[1] https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr50/